# Strange comma and backslash going through my db after form submit on multiple values on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

what`s up?

I've notice a strange behavior on my `app` when submiting form of multiple itens, I have a checkbox with 1-4 itens and when I select then the result comes as a string but with strange characters, like backlashes and comas, specially a strange coma before all of then. I`m using` gsub` to fix it, but I wish to know whats is going on? \

Result:

```rb
procedure: "[\"\", \"Administrativo\", \"Judicial\", \"Extrajudicial\"]"
.class => string
```

My View Form:

```html
          <div class="col-md-4 grid">
            <b><%= f.label "Procedimento" %></b>
            <%= f.collection_check_boxes :procedure, options_for_procedure, :second, :first do |cb|
              cb.label { cb.check_box + cb.text }
            end %>
          </div>
```

Collection (helper):

```rb
  def options_for_procedure
    procedure = ["Administrativo", "Administrativo"],
                  ["Judicial", "Judicial"],
                  ["Extrajudicial", "Extrajudicial"]
  end
```

Controller:

```rb
  def work_params
    params.require(:work).permit(
      procedure: [],
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are getting is a JSON string and you can simply parse it using the below command:

```
JSON.parse(params[:procedure])
```